# Как категоризировать строку по наличию в ней заданой группы посторонних символов?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть функция, которая принимает строку.

Строка, переданная функции, может:

1. Полностью состоять из букв (русских или английских);
2. Полностью состоять из цифр, знаков препинания и прочих символов (№, @, ~, #);
3. Состоять из букв, цифр, знаков препинания и прочих символов.

Мне необходимо проверять к какому пункту из списка выше можно отнести строку.

Я могу создать список всех символов и организовать проверку так:

```
def string_filter(string:str) -> None:

    ban_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                '+', '=', '*', '/', '%', '|', '@', '^', '>', '<',
                '?', '!', '#', '№', '_', '-', '(', ')', '{', '}',
                '$', '`', '~', '"', ';', ':', '[', ']']

    letters = True

    for i in ban_list:
        if i in string:
            letters = False

    if letters:
        print('В строке только буквы')
    else:
        print('В строке есть другие символы')

string_filter('only letters')
# Результат вызова >>> В строке только буквы

string_filter('123')
# Результат вызова >>> В строке есть другие символы
```

Но фактически, этот код не работает и не имеет никакого смысла.

Во-первых, список с кучей символов выглядит не очень эстетично.

Во-вторых, я могу проверить строку на соответствие только первому пункту. Сказать, что строка не содержит буквы абсолютно или состоит из букв **и** символов не получится.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как организовать проверку строки и определять, к какому пункту из списка выше она относится?

**UPD:**

Единственный случай, когда может вернуться единица - в строке есть **только буквы:**

```
print(str_category('abc'))
# Результат вызова >>> 1
```

Вернуться двойка может только тогда, когда в строке **нет букв абсолютно**, но могут быть цифры и прочие символы:

```
print(str_category('@1$;%3'))
# Результат вызова >>> 2
```

Вернуться тройка может только тогда, когда в строке есть **и** буквы, **и** обязательно какой-то символ, не являющийся буквой (это могут быть цифры, могут быть знаки):

```
print(str_category('abc@%4e'))
# Результат вызова >>> 3
```

**UPD2:**

```
In [60]: str_category("english words")
Out[60]: 1 # Буквы

In [61]: str_category("english words и русские слова")
Out[61]: 1 # Буквы

In [62]: str_category("english words & русские слова")
Out[62]: 3 # Буквы + какие-то символы

In [63]: str_category("3.1415")
Out[63]: 2 # Какие-то символы

In [64]: str_category("3.1415 - Pi !!!")
Out[64]: 3 # Буквы + какие-то символы

In [65]: str_category("3.1415, -{}[]) !!!")
Out[65]: 2 # Какие-то символы
```

Comment: Очень хочу, но, к сожалению, не знаю ничего о них. Мне следует почитать что-нибудь на эту тему?

Comment: В [первой редакции вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1112897/revisions) - `string_filter('only letters')` т.е. текст __с пробелом__ должен был вернуть `В строке только буквы`. Это условие все еще в силе или все-таки __только буквы__?

Comment: можете взять все тестовые строки из моего ответа и указать какой вы ожидаете результат для каждой из них? И может быть стоить добавить другие тесты, которые я не учел...

Comment: Да, простите, я забыл об этом :( Пробелы входят в только буквы

Comment: Сейчас сделаю, подождите, пожалуйста, пять минут

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Прошу прощения, за невнимательность

Comment: какой результат ожидается от `str_category("english words 123")` ?

Comment: `3 # Буквы + какие-то символы`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

vocab = {
    1: "Буквы",
    2: "Какие-то символы",
    3: "Буквы + какие-то символы"
}

def str_category(str_, vocab=vocab):
    # unicode_letters_pat = r"[^\W\d_]+$"
    if re.match(r"[\sa-zа-яё]+$", str_, flags=re.I):
        # only letters, space or tab
        return vocab.get(1)
    if re.search(r"[a-zа-яё]", str_, flags=re.I):
        # contains at least one letter
        return vocab.get(3)
    # the rest
    return vocab.get(2)
```

---

тесты:

```
In [147]: str_category("english words")
Out[147]: 'Буквы'

In [148]: str_category("english words и русские слова")
Out[148]: 'Буквы'

In [149]: str_category("english words & русские слова")
Out[149]: 'Буквы + какие-то символы'

In [150]: str_category("3.1415")
Out[150]: 'Какие-то символы'

In [151]: str_category("3.1415 - Pi !!!")
Out[151]: 'Буквы + какие-то символы'

In [152]: str_category("3.1415, -{}[]) !!!")
Out[152]: 'Какие-то символы'

In [153]: str_category("english words 123")
Out[153]: 'Буквы + какие-то символы'
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Буду разбирать сейчас. Сам бы я никогда не догадался

Comment: Прошу прощения, а можно сделать, чтобы 3 возвращалась только когда среди прочих символов есть буквы? Т.е. строка '№1' не вернет 3, а вернет 2, т.к в ней нет букв. Строка 'Часть№1' вернет 3, т.к. в ней присутствуют буквы. Я говорил об этом в вопросе, но, видимо, плохо объясняю :(

Comment: @MAXIM045, вы можете привести в вопросе несколько вариантов тестовых строк и то, что должно получиться на выходе (для тестов)? И еще что должна вернуть функция если строка не удовлетворяет ни одному из трех условий?

Comment: Попытался привести примеры. Я думаю, строка обязательно будет соответствовать одному из условий, и исключения не произойдут

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за обновление ответа! Это именно то, что я хотел :)